# Condition based show html in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I am new to Visualforce.

I am currently trying to display html on condition-based but I see there is no else condition so I have tried below but not able to succeed.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(activity.isanalytic == true, true, '')}" layout="none">
    <p>True Inside output panel</p>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(activity.isanalytic == true, '', false)}" layout="none">
    <p>False Inside output panel</p>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

On both the condition I want to display different divs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *not* render a section, return a false value, not an "empty string." Also, a Boolean value is already a Boolean value, so there's no need to convert it to a Boolean value via IF.

---

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!activity.isanalytic}" layout="none">
    <p>True Inside output panel</p>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!not(activity.isanalytic)}" layout="none">
    <p>False Inside output panel</p>
</apex:outputPanel>
```